# ADB with two nexus devices connected

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-maven-plugin

I have two devices, a Nexus 10 and a Nexus 7 tablets which I connect to my PC via two separate USB cables.

Windows Explorer pops up the Autoplay window for both of them when I do so they are recognised as devices.

I revoke USB debugging authorisations for both devices.

I plug Nexus 7 and authorise the computer to be the debugger.

```
List of devices attached
015d2d426b2ffe15        device
```

I disconnect Nexus 7 and connect Nexus 10.

I authorise the device and everything is fine.

```
List of devices attached
R32CB03S65R     device
```

I connect Nexus 7 again (without plugging out Nexus 10) and the device is not even recognised by ADB.

I restart the ADB server and no device is displayed and both devices need me to reauthorise the same computer. Even if I do no device gets recognised.

chome://inspect shows both devices, ADB and Eclipse are showing only one.

If by chance, both devices become visible in ADB, after a lot of random plugging in and out, I try to android:deploy my maven app in Eclipse. On nexus 7 it uninstalls the old one and installs the new one fine, but on nexus 10 I get a InstallException: TimeoutException 
(with timeout option set to 15s)

If I have nexus 10 connected and I connect nexus 7, nexus 10 disappears from the list and nexus 7 doesn't show up either.

Have anyone come across anything like this before?
Is there any special configuration needed to be able to work with both devices at the same time?

Any help greatly appreciated.

-J

Answer (score 0):

After trying to connect the devices to different USB ports on my PC, I found a combination that made it to work...

Comment: You should have included the "combination" because you answer is of no help to anyone as is.